# How to predict classes and print labels correctly in keras (python)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I've created a keras sequential LeNet model for predicting plant types and diseases using [this dataset.](https://www.kaggle.com/abdallahalidev/plantvillage-dataset) The problem is, `model.predict(x)` gives me an array of long decimals. `model.predict_classes(x)` gives me a single number inside a list like `[30]` or `[7]`. I don't know which one I should use and how I would get a label. I've tried matching the numbers up myself, but some of them make no sense, even though my model had 80% `val_acc`. Here is my script for predicting:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model, Sequential
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os

#  width is [0]
# height it [1]
x = 0
def prep_pic(img_path):
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    old_width  = img.size[0] 
    old_height = img.size[1]
    
    square_width = 150
    square_height = 150
    
    if old_height > old_width:
        square_width = old_width
        square_height = old_width
    
    if old_height <= old_width:
        square_width = old_height
        square_height = old_height
    
    left = (old_width - square_width)/2
    top = (old_height - square_height)/2
    right = (old_width + square_width)/2
    bottom = (old_height + square_height)/2

    img2 = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    img2.resize = (-1, 150, 150, 3)
    img2.save("pic.png")
    
    img3 = plt.imread("pic.png")
    #os.remove("pic.png")
    img3 = cv2.resize(img3, (150, 150))
    print(img3.shape)
    return img3.reshape(-1, 150, 150, 3)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.
    
# I know that my data prep is terrible, but it works. If you have any suggestion for this, please feel free to add it. 
prep_pic('../input/project-plantus/applescab.jpg')
model = Sequential()
model = load_model('../input/project-plantus/plantus_model.h5')
print(model.predict_classes([prep_pic('../input/project-plantus/applescab.jpg')]))
```

My model completely being inaccurate might be because of my data, or it isn't incorrect at all. I'll include my data prep for training my model here:

```
def train_data_gen(DIR, ID):
    for img in os.listdir(DIR)[:1000]:
        try:
            path = DIR + '/' + img
            img = plt.imread(path)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (150, 150))
            if img.shape == (150, 150, 3):
                x.append(img)
                y.append(ID)
        except:
            None
```

Comment: Did you divide your training input by 255 and didn't for the test input?

Comment: @NicolasGervais I tried doing that in a data_generator, but it gave terrible results.

Comment: You're supposed to do it for both